# What are elastic searches max and min dates by default?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Intro:**

We have a class annotated with `@Document` that has date fields.

E.g.

```
@Document(indexName = "notif-index", type = "notif-type", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
public class NotifEntry {

...

@Field(type = FieldType.Date)// ? (type=FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private Date pubDate;
```

When trying to insert data for years we are getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Bulk indexing has failures. Use ElasticsearchException.getFailedDocuments() for detailed messages [{104921=MapperParsingException[failed to parse [pubDate]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "-24303888000000" is malformed at "3888000000"];}]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.save(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor436.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
```

The specific date in question is: 1199-10-28 00:00:00

**Elastic Search Repositories:**

```
public interface NotifiEntryRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<NotifEntry, String> {    }
```

**Questions:**

IF we wanted to actually insert data like this how would we?
What is the max and min allowed dates in elastic search?

**Update:**

I tried converting the specific date to unix time format and am getting the following:
[image]

This is not the exact same number as in the exception, but it becomes obvious that elastic search is converting the Date into unix time (in MS) and the exception is taking place after that:

```
Invalid format: "-24303888000000" is malformed at "3888000000"]
-24303888000000 vs
-24304492800 * 1000ms
```

### Update 2

It seems underneath this error we have a JODA time parsing error:

Example:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "32503680000000" is malformed at "3680000000"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:826)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper$DateFieldType.parseStringValue(DateFieldMapper.java:366)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.innerParseCreateField(DateFieldMapper.java:534)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.NumberFieldMapper.parseCreateField(NumberFieldMapper.java:241)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:321)
    ... 21 more
```

### Update 3

I changed the specific dates from `java.util.date` but I am now getting the following error:

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [legalReference]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[unknown property [year]];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:329)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:311)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:328)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:254)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:584)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndexOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:563)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:211)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:157)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:657)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:287)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:378)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown property [year]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.innerParseCreateField(DateFieldMapper.java:520)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.NumberFieldMapper.parseCreateField(NumberFieldMapper.java:241)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:321)
```

### Update 3

It seems that changing the type from `@Field(type = FieldType.Date)` to `@Field(type = FieldType.String)` solves the problem for now. Though it would be interesting to know exactly what effect this has.