# What is the purpose of FieldType in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

### Intro

I had a strange issue with elastic search when I had used the following annotation:

`@Field(type = FieldType.Date, index = not_analyzed)`

And attempted to insert dates with years such as 1000 using the spring elastic search JPA repository.

See: [What are elastic searches max and min dates by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979884/what-are-elastic-searches-max-and-min-dates-by-default)

By changing the FieldType to String, it solved my problem and I did not get a weird error for extreme years.

### My question

What is the purpose of the FieldType enum and what do we use it for?

```
public enum FieldType {
    String,
    Integer,
    Long,
    Date,
    Float,
    Double,
    Boolean,
    Object,
    Auto,
    Nested,
    Ip,
    Attachment;

    private FieldType() {
    }
}
```

I read the documentation for elastic search and I don't really understand the use.

Comment: Story with dates sounds strange. Have you tried to report a bug to spring team?

Comment: @cybersoft No not yet. No one has actually answered my other question so I am thinking about opening a bug report in github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic search supports multiple data-types, Spring ***FieldType*** holds enum for allowed ElasticSearch datatypes. It specify in which datatype should elastic search maps the value while storing.

For e.g.

```
@Field(type = FieldType.String, index = not_analyzed)
private String name;
```

Above code means ElasticSearch should store name field as 'text'

[ElasticSearch data-types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html)